# Add composite primary key to all entities that inherit from a specific class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the generic class:

```
public class BaseTranslation<T, TEntity> : BaseEntity
    {
        public BaseTranslation() { }

        public T EntityId { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(2)]
        public string LanguageId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
    }
```

And an entity that inherits from that class:

```
public class SerieTranslation : BaseTranslation<byte, Serie>
    {
        public SerieTranslation() { }

    }
```

```
public class Serie
    {
        public Serie() { }

        [Key]
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Update { get; set; }
        public byte Order { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SerieTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

In the applicationdbcontext I'm trying to make a generic function that allows EntityId, LanguageId to be set as primary keys, I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseTranslation<,>))))
            {
                builder.Entity(entityType.Name, x =>
                {
                    x.HasKey("EntityId", "LanguageId");
                });
            }
}
```

Does anyone know what could be happening?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Since your base class is generic, you can not directly access its properties.

This will work

```
builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasKey("EntityId", "LanguageId");
builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasOne(typeof(Serie)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("EntityId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach we usually use, where we extract the entity configuration into their own method; we usually do this in a partial class of our `DbContext`.

First, define the base functionality in a generic method

```cs
    private static void ConfigureBaseEntity<TEntity>(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        builder.Property(entity => entity.Id)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
```

Then call it when registarting any entity

```cs
    private static void ConfigureMyEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
        ConfigureBaseEntity(builder);

        [...]
    }
```

And finally register it in the `OnModelCreating` of your `DbContext`

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MyEntity>(ConfigureMyEntity);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```